# in python I encountered error during using sort function

Tags: python, sorting

I have encountered a problem while using sort function of python.

```
>>>d = [23,45,67,5,4,23,45,89]
>>>d[5]
23
>>>g = d
>>>g.sort()
>>>d[5]
45
```

Is there any way, i can get g sorted without disturbing d.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list.sort` sorts [in-place](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists), and `g = d` assigns the reference to the list without copying it. Copy the list as `g = d[:]` before sorting, or use the built-in function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) instead:

```
g = sorted(d)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python **lists are mutable**, thus, to fix this change from `g = d` to `g = d[:]`

In other words, when doing `g = d`, `g` points to the same memory address that `d` does and by modifying `g`, `d` also gets the changes.

In order to avoid this, copy `d` by doing `d[:]`, which copies the entire memory of `d` to a new memory address.

Moreover, if you want to create a copy of a sub-list of `d`, you should `d[i:j]` that will make a new list that its first elements is the `i-th` element of `d` and the last one is the `(j-1)-th` element of it.

Remember numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, list and dicts are mutable.
See more at: http://ilian.i-n-i.org/python-interview-question-and-answers/#sthash.2WW5LTOA.dpuf

Comment: Note that `d = g` behaves the exact same way for all objects, mutable or not. The mutability just gives a more obvious way (there's always `id`/`is`) to make this sharing apparent.